# How to fix Unity Android build error: duplicate meta-data attribute value

Tags: unity-game-engine, attributes, google-play

## unity build error

```
D:\GitHub\WhyNotPJ_HC\WhyNotHC\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\launcher\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:94:13-43 Error:
    Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID@value value=(@string/app_id) from [:unityLibrary] AndroidManifest.xml:94:13-43
    is also present at [:unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib] AndroidManifest.xml:20:13-46 value=(\u003576325344850).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:92:9-94:46 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID@value value=(@string/app_id) from [:unityLibrary] AndroidManifest.xml:94:13-43
    is also present at [:unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib] AndroidManifest.xml:20:13-46 value=(\u003576325344850).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:92:9-94:46 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

please help how to solve this problem

I'm trying to build Unity Android, but it doesn't build with an error

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the log the conflict comes from the below element

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="">
    ...
```

which have different value for `android:value` attribute in two different **AndroidManifest.xml** :

- value `@string/app_id` in `[:unityLibrary]`
- value `\u003576325344850` in `[:unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib]`

---

To fix this issue you can try the suggestion given at the very top of your log that is to add the `tools:replace="android:value"` attribute to the `<meta-data>` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. This attribute will tell the **manifest merger tool** to replace the value with the one specified in your manifest.